# updateOnDuplicate not effect

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

hello i want insert data with bulkCreate ex:

`[
    {
        "typeId": 5,
        "devEui": "0094E796CBFCFEF9",
        "application_name": "Pressure No.10",
        "createdAt": "2020-02-05T08:07:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-05T08:07:17.000Z"
    }
]`

and my sequelize code :

```
 return models.sequelize.transaction(t=>{
            return models.iot_nodes.bulkCreate(data,{
                updateOnDuplicate: ["devEui",]
            })
        })
```

when i hit this code in first data that will be insert to db
my problem is when i hit again whit same data that not update, just insert in new row

iam using mysql db, laragon

log:

```
Executing (f202b84c-c5d8-4c67-954c-e22f96fb93d8): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `iot_nodes` (`id`,`typeId`,`devEui`,`application_name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,5,'0094E796CBFCFEF9','Pressure No.10','2020-02-05 08:07:17','2020-02-05 08:07:17') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id`=VALUES(`id`),`devEui`=VALUES(`devEui`);
Executing (f202b84c-c5d8-4c67-954c-e22f96fb93d8): COMMIT;
```

Comment: you don't include any index information in your question - `on duplicate _key_ update` only triggers if the insert would cause a conflict on a unique key.

Comment: can you give example sir ?

Comment: can you add `show create table iot_nodes` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to fit [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/06a0d26cb5109b6c2128c320fe657fa5d22d34cc/test/integration/model/bulk-create.test.js#L467) scenario based on the information. You want to update `devEui` field. `updateOnDuplicate` option:

> Fields to update if row key already exists (on duplicate key update)?

So, the `row key already exists` means the table must have a **unique** key or the primary key is duplicated when you insert the data.

E.g.

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

class IotNode extends Model {}
IotNode.init(
  {
    typeId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      unique: true,
    },
    devEui: DataTypes.STRING,
    application_name: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'iot_nodes' },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    const datas = [
      {
        typeId: 5,
        devEui: '0094E796CBFCFEF9',
        application_name: 'Pressure No.10',
        createdAt: '2020-02-05T08:07:17.000Z',
        updatedAt: '2020-02-05T08:07:17.000Z',
      },
    ];
    await IotNode.bulkCreate(datas, { updateOnDuplicate: ['devEui'] });
    await IotNode.bulkCreate(datas, { updateOnDuplicate: ['devEui'] });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

As you can see, I make the `typeId` unique and execute `IotNode.bulkCreate` twice. The generated SQL logs:

```sh
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "iot_nodes" ("id","typeId","devEui","application_name") VALUES (DEFAULT,5,'0094E796CBFCFEF9','Pressure No.10') ON CONFLICT ("typeId") DO UPDATE SET "devEui"=EXCLUDED."devEui" RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "iot_nodes" ("id","typeId","devEui","application_name") VALUES (DEFAULT,5,'0094E796CBFCFEF9','Pressure No.10') ON CONFLICT ("typeId") DO UPDATE SET "devEui"=EXCLUDED."devEui" RETURNING *;
```

sequelize use the unique `typeId` field as the duplicate key. Check the rows in the database:

```sh
=# select * from iot_nodes;
 id | typeId |      devEui      | application_name
----+--------+------------------+------------------
  1 |      5 | 0094E796CBFCFEF9 | Pressure No.10
(1 row)
```

The data row is upserted as expected.

If we remove the `unique: true` from `typeId` field. sequelize will use primary key as the duplicate key. Take a look below generated SQL and data rows in the database:

```sh
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "iot_nodes" ("id","typeId","devEui","application_name") VALUES (DEFAULT,5,'0094E796CBFCFEF9','Pressure No.10') ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "devEui"=EXCLUDED."devEui" RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "iot_nodes" ("id","typeId","devEui","application_name") VALUES (DEFAULT,5,'0094E796CBFCFEF9','Pressure No.10') ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "devEui"=EXCLUDED."devEui" RETURNING *;
```

```sh
=# select * from iot_nodes;
 id | typeId |      devEui      | application_name
----+--------+------------------+------------------
  1 |      5 | 0094E796CBFCFEF9 | Pressure No.10
  2 |      5 | 0094E796CBFCFEF9 | Pressure No.10
(2 rows)
```